# All Sunday between 2 dates by index using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I generate all the dates of Sunday between 2 dates per user

Here is my data frame :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['A', 'B'], 
                   'DATE_START':['2021-05-03', '2021-05-03'], 
                   'DATE_END':['2021-05-10', '2021-05-10']})
```

the final result I'm trying to find :

```
NAME    |  DATE_START |   DATE_END
--------------------------------------
A       |  2021-05-03 |    2021-05-03
A       |  2021-05-09 |    2021-05-09
A       |  2021-05-10 |    2021-05-10
B       |  2021-05-03 |    2021-05-03
B       |  2021-05-09 |    2021-05-09
B       |  2021-05-10 |    2021-05-10
```

I try something like this but I can't get the results:

```
def sundays(row):
    s = pd.date_range(row['DATE_START'], row['DATE_END'])
    return s[s.weekday == 6].to_list()
df.apply(sundays, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost done, but the formatting is a bit tricky.

Indeed, you have to format your columns as `pd.datetime`.

```
import pandas as pd
# I changed one of the dates so we can notice the result.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['A', 'B'], 
               'DATE_START':['2021-05-03', '2021-05-03'], 
               'DATE_END':['2021-05-21', '2021-05-10']})
df['DATE_START'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE_START'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df['DATE_END'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE_END'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

Then you can get the result of your function as a pandas Series :

```
def sundays(row):
    s = pd.date_range(row['DATE_START'], row['DATE_END'])
    return s[s.weekday == 6].to_list()

s = df.set_index("Name").apply(sundays, axis=1)
```

Then you can create a DataFrame from this Series, using pandas.DataFrame.explode() :

```
new_dates = pd.DataFrame({"DATE_START": s.explode(), "DATE_END": s.explode()}).reset_index()
```

It looks like this :

| . | Name | DATE_START | DATE_END |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 2021-05-09 | 2021-05-09 |
| 1 | A | 2021-05-16 | 2021-05-16 |
| 2 | B | 2021-05-09 | 2021-05-09 |

Finally, you can concatenate and sort both dataframes, while also resetting the index.

```
df = pd.concat((df, new_dates)).sort_values(["Name", "DATE_START"]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Final result :

| . | Name | DATE_START | DATE_END |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 2021-05-03 | 2021-05-21 |
| 1 | A | 2021-05-09 | 2021-05-09 |
| 2 | A | 2021-05-16 | 2021-05-16 |
| 3 | B | 2021-05-03 | 2021-05-10 |
| 4 | B | 2021-05-09 | 2021-05-09 |

If you wanted DATE_START to be equal to DATE_END, then you can do this instead:

```
s = df.set_index("Name").apply(sundays, axis=1)
new_dates = pd.DataFrame({"DATE_START": s.explode()}).reset_index()
df = pd.concat((df[["Name", "DATE_START"]], new_dates)).sort_values(["Name", "DATE_START"]).reset_index(drop=True)
df["DATE_END"] = df.DATE_START
```

Result:

| . | Name | DATE_START | DATE_END |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 2021-05-03 | 2021-05-03 |
| 1 | A | 2021-05-09 | 2021-05-09 |
| 2 | A | 2021-05-16 | 2021-05-16 |
| 3 | B | 2021-05-03 | 2021-05-03 |
| 4 | B | 2021-05-09 | 2021-05-09 |

Answer (score 0):

I tried to keep the solution similar to what you had. I think the issue was primarily with the string to date(time) conversion. See below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['A', 'B'],
                   'DATE_START':['2021-05-03', '2021-05-03'],
                   'DATE_END':['2021-05-10', '2021-05-10']})
df['DATE_START'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE_START'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df['DATE_END'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE_END'], format='%Y-%m-%d')


def sundays(row):
    start = row['DATE_START']
    while start.day_of_week != 6:
        start += dt.timedelta(days=1)
    return pd.date_range(start, row['DATE_END'], freq='7D')
    

df['range'] = df.apply(sundays, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank's for ur time @Rutger I got this :AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'day_of_week'

Comment: Can you try weekday instead? It might depend on the Python, Datetime or Pandas version